# Print word frequencies in a text file Perl

Tags: perl, scripting, scripting-language

I am trying to print the line count, word count, character count, and print out the words in a file as well as the amount of times they occur. I am getting errors with the last part (i.e. printing the words out and their occurences). Everything else works fine.

The error message I get:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at wc.pl line 34, near ""Number of lines: $lcnt\","Frequency"
        (Missing operator before Frequency?)
syntax error at wc.pl line 34, near ""Number of lines: $lcnt\","Frequency of "
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at wc.pl line 34.
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use strict;


my $lcnt = 0;
my $wcnt = 0;
my $ccnt = 0;
my %count;
my $word;
my $count;

open my $INFILE, '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!;

while( my $line = <$INFILE> ) {

$lcnt++;

$ccnt += length($line);

my @words = split(/\s+/, $line);

$wcnt += scalar(@words);

        foreach $count(@words) {
            $count{@words}++;
        }
}

foreach $word (sort keys %count) {


print "Number of characters: $ccnt\n","Number of words: $wcnt\n","Number of lines: $lcnt\","Frequency of words in the file: $word : $count{$word}";

}

close $INFILE;
```

This is what I need it to do:

**Sample input from txt file:**

```
This is a test, another test
#test# 234test test234
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Number of characters: 52
Number of words: 9
Number of lines: 2
Frequency of words in the file:
--------------------------------
#test#: 1
234test: 1
This: 1
a: 1
another: 1
is: 1
test: 1
test,: 1
test234: 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some logic errors, and some variable misuses in your code.  For logic errors, you really only need to print "Number of characters" once, but you put it in a loop, along with a few others that should be printed only once.  Pull them out of the loop.

Next, you weren't counting correctly; you were never actually using the word in your `foreach $count (@words)` line.  That's what I called a variable misuse; "`$count{@words}++`" is definitely not what you wanted.

There was one typo as well, which was causing Perl to issue a syntax error.  That was the missing `n` from `\n`.  An easy fix.

Finally, we'll try to do a better job of declaring variables in the narrowest scope possible.  Here's how it could look:

```
my $lcnt = 0;
my $wcnt = 0;
my $ccnt = 0;
my %count;

while( my $line = <DATA> ) {

    $lcnt++;
    $ccnt += length($line);

    my @words = split(/\s+/, $line);
    $wcnt += scalar(@words);

    foreach my $word (@words) {
        $count{$word}++;
    }
}

print "Number of characters: $ccnt\n",
      "Number of words: $wcnt\n",
      "Number of lines: $lcnt\n",
      "Frequency of words in the file:\n",
      "-----------------------------------\n";

foreach my $word (sort keys %count) {
    print "$word: $count{$word}\n";
}

__DATA__
This is a test, another test
#test# 234test test234
```

I switched over to using the `__DATA__` filehandle for now just for simplicity.  You can easily switch back to opening an input file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you meant to do a \n but instead did a \" which escapes the end of string quote.

Change from;

```
... "Number of lines: $lcnt\","Frequency of ...
```

To;

```
... "Number of lines: $lcnt\n","Frequency of ...
```